# Execute Upload Files Primefaces from External EventAction like button , link

Tags: jsf, primefaces

i have to create input form with attachment , so i want to execute file uploading in Submit button only so it will insert data into database and upload the files also ... i have searched and i didn't find any simple answer... thanks in advance 
image below 
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/CX4dc.png

i have tried to call upload event in button and disable ajax but it failed

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p:panel header="Upload Files">
        <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{uploadbean.upload}"
                      update=":aform"  allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png|pdf|doc|docx)$/" sizeLimit="30000000" />
    </p:panel>

    <p:commandButton ajax="false" action="#{uploadbean.upload}" value="Upload Files" />
</h:form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please check Primeface's example

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p:messages showDetail="true"/>
    <p:fileUpload value="#{fileUploadController.file}" mode="simple"/>
    <p:commandButton value="Submit" ajax="false"
                actionListener="#{fileUploadController.upload}"/>
</h:form>
```

in your bean:

```
public void upload() {
        if(file != null) {
            FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Succesful", file.getFileName() + " is uploaded.");
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
        }
    }
```

it's available at: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/fileUploadSimple.jsf .
you can find different file uploader at the left sidebar in "File" part.
good luck

Comment: Thanks for that , it is simple Upload i have attached image http://i.stack.imgur.com/CX4dc.png

Comment: @IbrahimDarwiesh no, you're using multiple file upload, not simple.

Comment: @ Luiggi Mendoza yes i am using multiple Upload and i am asking for this case for CALLING FileUploadEvent IN EXTERNAL Button OR Link To EXECUTE MULTIPLE UPLOAD

Comment: @IbrahimDarwiesh and the answer is: you can't.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza thanks for your answer so is there any way to create primefaces input form with attachment ? dead ?~locked i don't think so :D

Comment: @IbrahimDarwiesh yes: use it in `simple` form, not in `multiple`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza thanks but this cancel my question , and if so i will not ask ...i still waiting for answer